# Paypal POST return

Tags: php, paypal

We are having a big time trying to figure out why the return POST of after paypal payment is returning this after a payment:

```
["payment_status"]=> string(7) "Pending"
```

Can we have some help?

This is the main params that we send to paypal:

```
$html = '<form style="display:none;" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="' . JURI::root() . 'index.php?option=com_nbreal&view=property&id=' . $data['property'] . '">';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="' . JURI::root() . 'index.php?option=com_nbreal&view=property&id=' . $data['property'] . '">';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="_notify-synch:cmd" value="_notify-synch">';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://navegadev.no-ip.org/blandy/index.php?option=com_nbreal&view=properties&task=payment_status">';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and pull the Pending_Reason Variable. It should have more information on why the pending transaction is being held up. You should be able to retrieve it just like you retrieved the payment status variable.

There's more info on it here: [IPN and PDT Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/)

Comment: Yes, they are saying that this: unilateral: The payment is pending because it was made to an email address that is not yet registered or confirmed.

But is not true, because the account is verified.